# I want to save data in my hasura API database using the input field of my react app

Tags: reactjs, graphql, hasura

I have 2 tables in my Hasura API database, books(id,name,authorId) and authors(id,name). I want to insert data in these tables through the input field on my frontend.

I have the following mutations but I don't know how to define the schema in my frontend so that the data gets saved in the Hasura API tables

```
const ADD_BOOK = gql`
  mutation AddBook($type: String!) {
    addBook(type: $type) {
      name
    }
  }
`;
const ADD_AUTHOR = gql`
  mutation AddAuthor($type: String!) {
    addAuthor(type: $type) {
      name
    }
  }
`;
```

this is the input form

```
function Form(){

  let book,author;
  return (
    <Mutation mutation={ADD_BOOK}>
      {(addBook, { data }) => (        
        <Mutation mutation={ADD_AUTHOR}>
          {(addAuthor, { data }) => (
            <div>
              <form
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  addBook({ variables: { type: book.value } });
                  addAuthor({ variables: { type: author.value } });
                  book.value = "";
                  author.value = "";
                }}
              >
                <input
                  ref={node => {
                    book = node;
                  }}
                />
                <input
                  ref={node => {
                    author = node;
                  }}
                />
                <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          )}
        </Mutation>
      )}
    </Mutation>
  );

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The mutation for adding a book and author would be a [nested mutation](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/multiple-mutations.html) since both books and authors tables are related. Assuming you have created an `object relationship` called `author` from books table to authors table, the mutation would look like this:

```
const ADD_BOOK_WITH_AUTHOR = gql`
  mutation addBookWithAuthor($bookName: String!, $authorName: String!) {
    insert_books(objects: {
      name: $bookName, 
      author: {
        data: {
          name: $authorName
        }
      }
    }) {
      affected_rows
    }
  }
`;
```

And in your form, you will call the mutation with appropriate variables

```
addBook({ variables: { bookName: book.value, authorName: author.value } });
```